# Jenkins - Plugin for displaying applications deployed on Tomcat

Tags: jenkins

We have created a Job for migration of Applications from our Dev to Test environment and we checked the option "This Build is Parameterised" . In this we have hardcoded the list of applications that are deployed to the Tomcat instance in the Dev environment to the "CHOICE" parameter . Our requirement is , IF i give the TOmcat Instance details, the applications that are currently running on Tomcat should be dynamically populated into the "CHOICE" Parameter , . Please let me know if this is feasible and whether there is a plugin for the same.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two plugins that will support this,
assuming you have a way (some API) for retrieving the list of applications currently installed:

- **[Jenkins Dynamic Parameter Plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in)**
  This one allows  you to load values via a *Groovy* script.
- **[Extended Choice Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin)**
  This one can load a pre-generated text-file with values
  (you may need to run a "setup" step that generates that file).

Cheers